# While loops repeats with scanf equal to number of characters read

Tags: c

I have a program that is meant to take commands the first question is the format the commands will be taken in command line or file by typing c or f
if neither is typed the while loop repeats without allowing input equal to the number of characters in the incorrect input instead of stopping and allowing scanf to grab input again. I don't use it's return values at any point so I am at a loss as to why this happens. correctly entering 'f' or 'c' does not cause the problem.
any help would be greatly appreciated

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define true 1
#define false 0
typedef int bool;

double **temp_array;
double temp1d_array[36];
char consolep[100];
char *fp1;
FILE *fp;
char string_IO1[50];
char string_temp[50];
char buffer[50];
char current_command[10];
int halt = 0;
char *strtodptr;

void main(){
printf("welcome \n");
char IO;
char read[250];
char file_console;
int IO_method = 0;
char command[10];
char type_IO;
char type_of_var_IO;
char dim_IO[3];
char array_string_IO[40];

//console or file

//decide IO Method loop 1
while (IO_method==0)
{
    printf("please type 'c'for console or 'f' for file to select input type\n");
    scanf("%c", &file_console);

//if console
if(file_console =='c')
{
    IO_method=1;
    printf("method is console\n");

}

//if file
    else if(file_console=='f')
    {
        IO_method=2;
        printf("method is file\n");
        printf("please enter a file directory\n");
        scanf("%s",&string_IO1);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("invalid entry\n");  
        file_console=NULL;
        IO_method=0;
    }
}}//code here continues but i compiled it without and has no bearing on the error.
```

Comment: that only works for 1 character wrong answers typing "ccccc" still causes the repeat

Comment: posted code does not compile

Comment: fixed code compilation, forgot my imports

Comment: Main issue with compilation seems to be missing declaration for `string_IO1`.

Comment: Tip: delete `#define scan_for_add scanf("%s")` for production code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calls to `scanf()` in the posted code leave characters behind in the input stream. If, for example, the user enters **g** at the first prompt, pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after, the `\n` character is left behind. If the user enters more than one character, the extra characters are left behind. The later calls to I/O functions will pick up these unexpected characters, causing the program to misbehave.

One solution is to write a little function to clear the input stream after such I/O function calls:

```
void clear_input(void)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

This function discards any characters that remain in the input stream (up to and including the first newline character). Note that `c` must be an `int` to ensure that `EOF` is handled correctly. Also note that this function should only be called when the input stream is not empty; an empty input stream will cause the call to `getchar()` to block, waiting for input.

For example, after the first call to `scanf()` you know that there is at least a `\n` character still in the input stream (maybe more characters preceding the newline); just call `clear_input()` to clean the input stream before the next I/O call:

```
scanf("%c", &file_console);
clear_input();
```

The value returned by `scanf()` should be checked in robust code; the number of successful assignments made is returned, or `EOF` in rare the event of an error. This can help to validate input.

A better option would be to use `fgets()` to read from `stdin` and fetch a line of input to a buffer, and then use `sscanf()` to parse the buffer. One advantage here is that `fgets()` will read all characters up to, and including, a newline character, provided there is adequate space in the buffer. So, allocate a generous `buffer[]` to make it likely that no reasonable input can fail to be contained in the buffer. If you need to be more careful, you can check the input buffer for a `\n` character (using `strchr()`, for example). If the `\n` character is found in the buffer, then the input stream is empty, otherwise there are extra characters left behind, and the `clear_input()` function can be called to clean things up:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
...
char buffer[1000];
char end;
while (IO_method==0)
{
    printf("please type 'c'for console or 'f' for file to select input type\n");
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) {
        /* Handle input error */
        perror("Error in fgets()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* May need to clear input stream, if input is too large */
    if (strchr(buffer, '\n') == NULL) {
        clear_input();
    }

    /* Input again if input is not as expected */
    if (sscanf(buffer, "%c%c", &file_console, &end) != 2 || end != '\n') {
        continue;
    }
...
```

Here, `buffer[]` is declared with a generous size to hold all reasonable inputs. `fgets()` places the input in `buffer`, up to and including the newline (space-permitting). Note that the return value from `fgets()` is checked; a null pointer is returned if there is a rare I/O error. Next, `strchr()` is used to check for the `\n` in `buffer`; it is expected to be present, but if not, a null pointer is returned, signalling that there are still characters in the input stream to be cleared. Next, `sscanf()` is used to parse the buffer. Here, note that `end` is used store the character after the user-input character. In expected input, this is a `\n` character. If the user enters too many characters, testing `end` will reveal this, and input is taken again.

Also note that in the posted code, `string_IO1` was not declared (and not a great name, since the characters in `IO1` are difficult to distinguish on a screen); if this is a character array, then the call to `scanf()` should have looked like:

```
scanf("%s",string_IO1);
```

And, `file_console` has been declared as a `char`, so the assigment `file_console = NULL;` is wrong, since `NULL` is the null pointer macro, not an integer type.

Comment: thank you very much i've been looking for ways online to try and clear the stream. 
IT WORKED BEAUTIFULLY
Now is there a way to make this safe for if the input stream is empty already so I can toss a few in just to be safe? or is there a built in c function that can check if the stream is clean?

Comment: The way to do this is _not_ to call it when the input stream is empty. Calling after `scanf()` is safe, so long as you don't use some other trickery to remove extra characters first. There is no need to use extra calls for safety, though. I will add to the example shortly to maybe address your concerns a bit more....

Comment: "... discards any characters that remain in the input stream."  --> closer to "... discards characters in the input stream up to the end-of-line."